# Send function as parameter in rtk query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a service that is getting user token from a react hook, so I can't use the service directly in the Redux Toolkit Query (RTKQ) API. So I'm trying to use composition and pass the service later when the mutation gets called.

Is it possible to pass the service as an argument to the RTKQ function?

I tried to do this. It works but I get an error log that says a non-serializable data is stored in the state.

my example mutation:

```
removeItemById: builder.mutation<void, {service: ItemService; uuid: string}>({
  invalidatesTags: ['Beneficiaries'],
  queryFn: async ({ service, uuid }) => {
    const result = await service.remove(uuid);
    return { data: result };
  },
})
```

usage:

```
const [remove, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess }] = useRemoveItemByIdMutation();

const handleRemove = () => {
  remove({service: itemService, uuid});
};
```

error:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `item.queries.getItems({}).originalArgs.add`
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `service`, as a function, is a non-serializable value.

If you were working with a query instead of a mutation you could use the [serializeQueryArgs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs-1) property on the endpoint. Mutations don't appear to allow for this according to the docs.

What I'd suggest instead then is to create and export a "services" object that packs up the various services that you want callable from the API slice and provide `service` as a lookup key.

Example:

```js
import itemService from '../itemService';
... other service imports ...

type Service = ItemService | ... other service types ...;

interface Services = {
  [key: string]: Service;
}

export services: Services = {
  item: itemService,
  ... other services ...
};
```

```js
import { serivces } from '../services';

...

removeItemById: builder.mutation<void, { service: string; uuid: string }>({
  invalidatesTags: ['Beneficiaries'],
  queryFn: async ({ service, uuid }) => {
    const result = await services[service].remove(uuid);
    return { data: result };
  },
}),
```

```js
const [
  remove,
  { isLoading, isError, isSuccess }
] = useRemoveItemByIdMutation();

const handleRemove = () => {
  remove({ service: "item", uuid });
};
```

Comment: the problem is, the service functions are result of a react hook. so i cant use directly in the `createApi` function.

Comment: what i ended up doing was passing the services with a `Symbol` key so it doesn't get serialized.